# Installation failed: Bad credentials (401) travis ci with R

Tags: r, travis-ci

My .travis.yml is as follows:

```
language: r
sudo: required
cache: packages

before_install:
  - echo -e "machine github.com\n  login $CI_USER_TOKEN" >> ~/.netrc
  - chmod 755 ./travis-tool.sh

install:
  - ./travis-tool.sh install_github RcppCore/Rcpp
  - ./travis-tool.sh install_github rstats-db/DBI
  - ./travis-tool.sh install_github rstats-db/RPostgres
```

However, I am not able install Rcpp package. it is throwing following error

```
+InstallGithub RcppCore/Rcpp
+EnsureDevtools
+Rscript -e 'if (!("devtools" %in% rownames(installed.packages()))) q(status=1)'
+echo 'Installing GitHub packages: RcppCore/Rcpp'
Installing GitHub packages: RcppCore/Rcpp
+Rscript -e 'devtools::install_github(commandArgs(TRUE),host = '\''https://api.github.com'\'', dependencies = FALSE)' RcppCore/Rcpp
Using GitHub PAT from envvar GITHUB_PAT
Downloading GitHub repo RcppCore/Rcpp@master
from URL https://api.github.com/repos/RcppCore/Rcpp/zipball/master
Installation failed: Bad credentials (401)
```

I copied travis-tools.sh file from [github](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/craigcitro/r-travis/master/scripts/travis-tool.sh)

Any help is appreciated

Comment: I am able to install package using same command in my computer & docker.

Comment: Are you logging in using modified `~/.netrc` on docker/computer as well?

Comment: Also, I noticed "GITHUB_PAT" (env variable) was used for login, so it might happen that .netrc was ignored, just a guess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't tell why .netrc approach didn't work (probably R-client just ignores it unlike curl), but according to [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/devtools/versions/1.13.3/topics/install_github), the right way to login using `install_github` is to set `GITHUB_PAT` environment variable. Perhaps, something like:

```
env:
  - GITHUB_PAT=$CI_USER_TOKEN
```

Basically, your log suggests that `GITHUB_PAT` was used for login attempt:

> +Rscript -e 'devtools::install_github(commandArgs(TRUE),host = '\''https://api.github.com'\'', dependencies = FALSE)' RcppCore/Rcpp
>
> Using GitHub PAT from envvar GITHUB_PAT

You can also read this article: https://www.r-bloggers.com/using-travis-make-sure-you-use-a-github-pat/